# the speak function in web speech in java script doesn't work inside foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

The speak function in web speech in java script doesn't work inside foreach loop ?

```
if(com1[0]=="timeline")
{

$(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'get_tweets.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {

        if (typeof response.errors === 'undefined' || response.errors.length < 1) {

            var $tweets = $('<p></p>');
            $.each(response, function(i, obj) {

             var result="say next tweet ";
                             var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(result);
                             synth.speak(msg);  

              alert(i);
                $tweets.append('tweet' +'<br>' + obj.text + '<br>');
                $('.tweets-container').html($tweets);

            });
        }
```

Comment: You will probably need to wait for the speak method to return. I would bet that it is an async method. You might need to see if there is a callback method you can use to start the next speak call.

Comment: speak() does not take a callback. 'The speak() method of the SpeechSynthesis interface adds an utterance to the utterance queue; it will be spoken when any other utterances queued before it have been spoken.'

Comment: I can use synth.speak in a for loop. Are you certain you are calling it more than once?